# How do market-makers make a profit in the bond markets?

Tags: trading, bonds, market-making

Do they sell at ask, buy at bid? Meanwhile, investors buy at ask and sell at bid. So, do the market-makers profit from the bid-ask spread?

Comment: Are you sure this is specific to the bond markets? Is market-making in equities different?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo well its the same, but I asked specifically about the bonds market, as it concerns my case.